# Espresso with hamcrest 1.3

Tags: android, android-espresso, hamcrest

Is there a way to use Espresso with Hamcrest 1.3? I can get it to compile, but I end up with runtime exceptions:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/test/espresso/Espresso
```

Everything is fine when I use hamcrest 1.1

The root of the problem is this stuff:

```
VFY: unable to resolve static method 31131: Lorg/hamcrest/Matchers;.is (Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/hamcrest/Matcher;
```

the only solution I see at the moment is to comile espresso with hamcrest 1.3 - but I would love to use the stock version - so any Idea how to avoid using a own version would be nice!

Comment: bit of follow-up here https://plus.google.com/+misterligi/posts/EzCybiqDxft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espresso 2.2 now uses hamcrest 1.3 so the problem is gone: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4a51oVb59H6

Answer (score 0):

Try Espresso 2.0 where all the 3rd parties code is decoupled. It will solve your problem.